# Помогите расшифровать

Tags: кодировка, шифрование

Здравствуйте, подскажите что это за шифровка

> aHR0cDovL3NlcmlhbG9ubGluZS5uZXQvcGwve2FudGlsaWNofS9jaGVyZXBhc2hraV9uaW5kemlhXzEwLnR4dHx8fDE3NzM=

Чем ее можно расшифровать или в каком направлении копать?

Answer (score 6):

Это [Base-64](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) - зашифровано "послание"

> http://serialonline.net/pl/{antilich}/cherepashki_nindzia_10.txt|||1773

Для дешифровки [втыкать сюда](http://www.base64.ru/)

**Update** Вообще то это не шифровка, а кодирование. Обычно применяется для кодирования бинарных данных в ASCII символику.

Answer (score 2):

Это BASE64

```
avp@avp-xub11:~/src/dispro$ echo -n  aHR0cDovL3NlcmlhbG9ubGluZS5uZXQvcGwve2FudGlsaWNofS9jaGVyZXBhc2hraV9uaW5kemlhXzEwLnR4dHx8fDE3NzM= | base64 -d
http://serialonline.net/pl/{antilich}/cherepashki_nindzia_10.txt|||1773avp@avp-xub11:~/src/dispro$
```

т.е. закодирован текст

```
http://serialonline.net/pl/{antilich}/cherepashki_nindzia_10.txt|||1773
```